# Mystified by jQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, datepicker, default

I have scoured various forums to find an answer to this. To no avail. I have a solution of sorts, below, it does what I want but it throws an error in console. If I remove the offending  'asString()', the error disappears, sure, but I don't see the date in the input field.

HTML

```
<input class='datepicker' value='[yyyy-mm-dd]' type='text' name='date_taken' />
```

JQuery

```
function dp() {
  var temp = document.getElementById("last_date").value;
  var bits = temp.split("-");
  bits[1]--; if(bits[1]==0){bits[1]=12;}
  var lastDate = new Date(bits[0],bits[1],bits[2]);
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    showOtherMonths: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    changeMonth: false,
    changeYear: false,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    defaultDate: lastDate,
    setDate: lastDate
    });
   $('.datepicker').datepicker().val(lastDate.asString()).trigger('change');
  }
```

What I want to achieve is for the date (dynamically generated) to appear in the input field, be highlighted by the datepicker and be the value returned when the form is submitted. In other words, the user only needs to change the date if needed.

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: `.asString()` is not a known Date prototype method. Did you mean `.toString()`?

Comment: That's the thing.  I know asString() is not a valid method. That's what throws the error. But if I change it to toString(), the error disappears but the routine doesn't work. No date shown in the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$.datepicker.formatDate` utility function to format a Date instance and set the value on the input field.

You needn't trigger a `change` event as this does nothing until the datepicker opens. If you want to trigger the dialog visibility immediately then use the `.datepicker("show")` method.

```js
$(function() {
  var lastDate = new Date("2019-06-01");
  var dateFormat = "yy-mm-dd";
  $("#datepicker")
    .datepicker({
      showOtherMonths: true,
      showButtonPanel: true,
      selectOtherMonths: true,
      changeMonth: false,
      changeYear: false,
      dateFormat: dateFormat,
      defaultDate: lastDate,
      setDate: lastDate
    })
    .val($.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, lastDate));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```